# Updating scrapy post body parameter

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working with the scrapy FormRequest.from_response object. I have:

```
   x = FormRequest.from_response(response,formname='aspnetForm', headers=post_headers , url=url,  callback=self.test1)
```

In a debugger:

```
>>> x.body
ContentPlaceHolder1%24chkIncludeParty=on&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlMotions=Y&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnSearch=Search'
```

I want to update field 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlMotions' Does scrapy offer an easy way to update parameters. I see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.replace in the docs, but I'm not sure if this would be helpful here.